# Sigma finite measure generated by field

Tags: measure-theory

This is a question from Strichartz, The Way of Analysis (qu 15 in 15.1.4):

If $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure on a $\sigma$-field $F_{1}$ generated by a field $F$, show that in the decomposition $X=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}X_{j}$ with $\mu(X_{j})<\infty$ it is possible to take each $X_{j}$ in $F$.

I can see how "the conclusion follows from the conclusion" - given the result that the $X_{j}$ can lie in $F$, you can get a uniqueness of $\sigma$-finite measures result, and deduce that the measure $\mu$ is the same as the measure given from the Caratheodory extension theorem applied to the restriction of $\mu$ to $F$; then from the definition of outer measure any measurable set $X$ can be approximated by a countable union of elements of $F$ which contain it and whose measure sums to $\epsilon$ greater than the measure of $X$, from which the result follows. I can't see how to prove the uniqueness of measures result just from sigma finiteness though.

It's possible the answer relies on other results or problems in the book, I haven't been through it thoroughly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **not** true, as Exercise 23 from §1.4 of Folland's "Real Analysis" shows:

If we let $\mathcal{A}$ denote the collection of all finite disjoint unions (including the "empty union", i.e. the empty set) of sets of the form $(a,b] \cap \Bbb{Q}$ with $-\infty \leq a < b \leq \infty$, then one can show that $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra (you would call that a field).

But if we let $\mu$ be the counting measure on $\Bbb{Q}$ (with the whole power set as the domain of definition), one can show (because of $\{a\} = \bigcap_n (a - 1/n, a]$) that the power-set $\sigma$-algebra is generated by $\mathcal{A}$.

Also, $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, because $\Bbb{Q}$ is countable.

But one can not write $\Bbb{Q} = \bigcup_n F_n$ with $F_n \in \mathcal{A}$ of finite measure, because each set in $\mathcal{A}$ except the empty set is infinite.

Comment: Wow! In textbooks I've seen incorrectly stated questions and typos, but never a question that was just completely false. No wonder I was having trouble proving it. Cheers!